# echoing to text box in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something simple to learn how to do a query and then put the answer into a box. I have a HTML file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="results.php" method="post">Search: <input name="term" type="text" /><br />    
<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
<p>Answer: <input name="answer" type="text" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the php code is:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'host.com';
$username = 'ratetable';
$password = 'mypassword';
$term = (int) $_GET['term'];

try 
{
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ratetable", $username, $password);
   //echo 'Connected to database<br />';

   foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<= ' . $term . ' ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1') as $row) {
       echo "<input type='text' name='answer' value='" . $row['ratepermile'] . "'>";
   }
}         
catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       throw($e);
   }
?>
```

So I'm trying to put ratepermile, a field in the database, into the 'answer' text box. What I get is the screen clears, but no form and no result, even after I comment out the 'connected to database' echo line and use something that I know exists in the database.

How can I keep the form on screen and echo to the text box?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: So you get a blank page?

Comment: Your form is using `method="post"`, but your PHP is looking at `$_GET['term']`.

Comment: As @RocketHazmat said, you need to look for POST parameters instead of GET, ideally in such cases you should log what you are getting at each step to debug. Specifically if your query us returning any rows etc. Also look at your webserver error log and see if you see anything unusual there.

Comment: @Jeffrey, the answer box appears on a second page but I want the form to remain on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is `POST`ing the data (`method="post"`), but your PHP script is looking in the `$_GET` aray.

You need to get the data from `$_POST` instead.

```
$term = (int) $_POST['term'];
```

Comment: Oh man, I was thinking it needed GET because of POST lol. The form disappears and only displays the answer box, but not the input and submit. How can I stablize that? I tried doing something with div earlier (under the submit button) and I don't think I did it right. Like: <div id="results">  (the text box to echo to) </div>

Comment: @Shawn: When you submit the form, you are actually navigating to a *new page*.  If you don't want that, look into POSTing the form with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the above POST issue. If you wish to keep the form on the page and not reload the page you need to look into [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_REQUEST in order to avoid these confusions. Whether you use method="post" or method="get", you can fetch the value through this.